# edit text height increases while changing the orientation

Tags: android, size, android-edittext, orientation-changes

In my app i am locking the screen orientation as portrait. But i am changing this when user tap on an edit text box.in portrait mode it is working fine.but in landscape mode edit text height is almost double the actual size.given below is my xml for edit text.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/mylist_AddNewFFtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mylist_stdcenterelement"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend|actionGo|actionDone"
        android:inputType="text|textCapWords"
        android:maxLength="1000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

i have removed the weight=1 property.but it does not work. How can i solv this issue?

Comment: Change the width and height to "wrap_parent" which means that the view will just big enough to enclose its content.

Comment: then before i start typing the size of the edit box will be zero rite?

Comment: No, It will not be zero! try this out.

Comment: yeah size is not zero...but it does not solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mylist_AddNewFFtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/mylist_stdcenterelement"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend|actionGo|actionDone"
    android:inputType="text|textCapWords"
    android:maxLength="1000"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

make your layout height 0dp to wrap_content because you are trying to insert text into 0dp height edit text box

Comment: that is why i am giving weight property.